# use ss stream to read words in line of text file and assign to student

Tags: c++

I need to read a line of a text file and each word is seperated by a single space. The line stores the id, firstname, lastname, department, and gpa in that order. A line in the text file looks like this:

`9528951 Adney Smith CS 4.2 //id    fname lname dept gpa`

main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    // Add your code here:
    string line;
    stringstream ss(line);
    ifstream myfile("enroll_test.txt");
    HashTable<string> ht;
    string id, fname, lname, dept, gpa;

    if (!myfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File failed to open" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        ss >> id >> fname >> lname >> dept >> gpa;
        Student<string> student;// = new Student(fname, lname, gpa, dept);
        student.setFirstName(fname);
        student.setLastName(lname);
        student.setGPA(gpa);
        student.setDepartment(dept);
        // id = line.substr(0, line.find(" "));
        ht.insert(id, student);
    }
    myfile.close();

    ht.displayHash();
    
    // else cout << "Unable to open file";
    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
```

When I run the debugger it shows the error happens when I try to insert into the hashTable. It takes me string_conversion.h and throws the invalid argument. In the debugger there are no values set for the student variables so I believe I used ss stream wrong to read the line and parse. Anyone know how I can solve this? By the way I am using stoi() to convert the id to an int the rest can be left as strings.

I tried using ss stream but I dont believe I am implementing it right.

Comment: please show a [mre], at a guess the input to `stoi` is not a number

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

your error is probably because `id` is an empty string because `ss` was never filled.

```cpp
string line;
stringstream ss(line);
```

this just constructs `ss` with an initial value of a **copy** of the string in `line` which is empty.

```cpp
while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        ss >> id >> fname >> lname >> dept >> gpa;
```

the data is in `line`, but it won't be in `ss` as it was only a copy of `line` initial value, so just pass `line` to `ss` to consume it on every line.

```cpp
while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        ss << line;
        ss >> id >> fname >> lname >> dept >> gpa;
```

**Edit:** as noted by @user4581301 , this won't clear the content of `ss` on every loop iteration, so you should instead construct `ss` inside your loop.

```cpp
while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        istringstream ss(line);
        ss >> id >> fname >> lname >> dept >> gpa;
```

and remove its definition from the top of the code.

Comment: Side note: If you are going to construct a `std::stringstream` for reading only, you should use `std::istringstream` instead.

Comment: thanks it wasnt working untill @user4581301 suggested to clear the content.